# Is it possible to locate the android device without gps and network?

Tags: android, location

We have an application which need to locate the device(the user) within 200 meters.

Use case:
Out client team have almost 20+ people, they will work separated but within a certain geographic extent(less than 200m). And all of them will take an android device (without network support)The manager of the team need to know the location and distance relative to himself.

I have though that using the GPS to get the location, but I still have two more problem:

1 The work place maybe inside a build, so I am afraid it is hard to get the GPS signal.

2 Get the location.

Event I get the location through the gps, how can I transform the message from the other device to that of the manager? Since there is no network available.

I hope someone can give me some suggestions.

Comment: You cant use GPS indoors. And without network support ... you can only use alternatives like bluetooth. But your range is way to big, so you will have to find somekind of adhoc solution or something.

Comment: When you say "No network support", what about text messages ?

Comment: They can send messages.

Comment: Let's slightly transform your use case, as noted in italics: "Use case: Out client team have almost 20+ people, they will work separated but within a certain geographic extent(less than 200m). And all of them will take *a flower*. The manager of the team need to know the location and distance relative to himself." The solution is for the manager to yell each team member's name loudly, asking that person to wave, then estimate the member's location and distance relative to himself. With that in mind, please explain how a GPS-less and network-less Android device is better than a flower.

Comment: @CommonsWare: You must be kidding.

Comment: Not really. If none of the devices know where they are, and they are incapable of communicating, they are no better than a flower. You may be better served enumerating what technologies these Android devices *do* have, if they cannot use GPS or a network, with which you might think that the devices could figure out where they are or communicate.

Answer (score 1):

You can investigate the NFC tags with a system to detect the tags and identify the different android devices with NFC feature

Comment: It seems that the NFC communication distance is no more than a few centimetres(http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Near_field_communication) Have I miss anything?

Comment: Yes you are right, but if you have no WIFI or Bluetooth, you can use them for instance to communicate with the smartphones and set an RFID system for the network , Just an Idea